# hidesBottomBarWhen pushed with vertically a centered layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Very simple.

I have a UIViewController that I want to push, but I want the UITabBar to drop away. So, I set the "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" flag. Works great, except...

The view I'm pushing has one main view, which is vertically centered, using autolayout constraints.

The effect is that the view is drawn centered (as if the UITabBar is still there), then it jumps down 20 or so points (1/2 the height of the UITabBar).

It appears that the only way I can reliably handle this is to just keep my view hidden, and then check the state of the tab-bar, (check the hidden flag), and then hide it. And then when my viewController goes away, make the tab bar visible.

I'd really like to *not* write the extra code to do all this, as there is this really nice flag here, and I don't want to remember the state of the tab-bar... this view might be used elsewhere.

It just seems really odd to me that the centering of the layout isn't calculated *knowing* that the tab-bar is going away. The flag is on the view's owning VC, so it seems like this calculation should be able to be done as part of the normal auto-layout rules.

If there's a good way to force Autolayout to resolve with the *correct* center, please let me know.

Comment: Is "Extend Edges>Under Bottom Bars" checked in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're loading your view controller from Storyboard.

First, check the bottom constraint for a view - if it fixed to parent view, or to the `bottomLayoutGuide`

Then set up appearance of your view controller in the storyboard accordingly (show or hide tab bar, toolbar, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my case, I should've set the bottom constraint to the parent-view's bottom, instead of the bottomLayoutGuide.